# XArray: add a "layer" of data to NetCDF

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

**Set up**

suppose I have a NetCDF file that stores a number of rasters indexed by `date`, `longitudes` and `latitudes`, loaded in memory with `XArray` with name "stack":

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (date: 1, lat: 2000, lon: 7200)
Coordinates:
  * date      (date) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01
  * lat       (lat) float64 49.97 49.92 49.87 49.82 ... -49.88 -49.93 -49.98
  * lon       (lon) float64 -180.0 -179.9 -179.9 -179.8 ... 179.9 179.9 180.0
Data variables:
    rainfall  (date, lat, lon) float64 ...
```

**task**

to add a new `date` to the stack.

**method**

my approach is to create a `Dataset` "new" from the raster with the same indices as the NetCDF loaded:

```
xr.DataArray(
     <some numpy data>,
     dims=['date', 'lat', 'lon'],
     coords={
         'date': [<some datetime64>],
         'lat': <same list of latitudes>,
         'lon': <same list of longitudes>
     },
     name='rainfall'
).to_dataset()
```

and then concatenate:

```
merged = xr.concat([stack, new], dim='date')
```

This works but is not very elegant and being new to XArray maybe there is a better way to go about this, for example just with some indexing routines say adding a new `date` and data; something like:

```
stack[<new_date>] = <some numpy data>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some work I have a workaround using `netCDF4-python` which is useful if you are looking for a way not to load the entire netCDF in memory at once.

The original netCDF file is processed with `XArray` but I fallback to `netCDF4` for this particular operation.

An example follows where I want to add a timestep to the *unlimited* variable `date`. The other 2 variables are *longitudes* and *latitudes*.

First off I open the netCDF using netCDF4 and read the variables `date` that I will extend as well as the `data`

```
d = Dataset('dataset.nc', 'a')
dt = d.variables['date']
data = d.variables['data']
```

after that I add the numpy array to a slice:

```
data[len(dt):len(dt)+1, :,:] = <some numpy data>
```

and finally add the extra time step:

```
from datetime import datetime
from netCDF4 import date2num
dt[len(dt)-1] = date2num(datetime(<year>, <month>, <day>), dt.units)
```

Hope for it to be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`reindex`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.reindex.html#xarray.DataArray.reindex) to extend the original DataArray, and then [assign value with indexing](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#assigning-values-with-indexing).

```py
extra_date = <some datetime64>
date_extended = np.concatenate([stack.date, [extra_date]]
# this will extend the arrays and place NaNs in the new position
stack_extended = stack.reindex({'date': date_extended})
# now assign to that position
stack_extended.loc[dict(date=extra_data)] = <some numpy data>
```

Comment: hey thanks for this. I did try to use `.loc` before but actually I don't think you can assign data to it, i.e. you get `TypeError: '_LocIndexer' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: loc does in general support item assignment
`
da = xr.DataArray([0, 0, 0], dims=['x'], coords={'x': [0, 1, 2]})
da.loc[dict(x=1)] = 5
`

What is your `xarray.__version__`?

Comment: but only if I have the `x=1` already in there. What if I want to add a new one, say `da.loc[dict(x=3)] = 5` ? I am running the conda distribution v 0.11.